# How to give a Program more permissions, than the user starting it

Tags: .net, windows, file-permissions

I am programming an application (.Net) to create some reports which have to be written into a special folder.
The problem is: the users of my application should have read permission in this folder, but are not allowed to write or change anything. How can I create files in this folder if the program inherits the Permissions from the users?

I am not really firm with the Windows-Permissions, so I don't know if it can be handled by them.

Can someone point me to a general direction?

Comment: There's no simple way to do this - and if you can, you then have to **ensure** that there's no way to subvert your program into writing inappropriately into that directory - that's a lot of work you're creating for yourself.

Comment: yeah i thought as much. But maybe there a workaround. Maybe you can create a special user, and the application can use the permission from this useraccount

Comment: If you create a *special user* for your program to operate under, you then have to store its credentials somewhere that the program can access **when running as the standard user**. That means that, ultimately, the credentials are available to the standard user which makes the security potentially ineffective (Obviously you could encrypt the credentials, which would stop the majority of users, but it wouldn't stand in the way of anyone even slightly technically able and/or determined).

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way is to create a service that has write permissions to the folder, so it can act as a "broker" for requests to write to the folder. Your process would then look like this:

1. [PROGRAM] Creates report output in the temporary files path
2. [PROGRAM] Informs [SERVICE] that report output X is available in the temporary files path
3. [SERVICE] Copies report output X from temporary files path to appropriate restricted location
4. [SERVICE] Informs [PROGRAM] that the output has been copied
5. [PROGRAM] Access output from the restricted location.

Having a separate broker process that mediates access to restricted locations is quite common now and is one of the techniques emoployed by Internet Explorer, amongst others, to allow it to operate with UAC and restricted file system access by default.

You can code your broker service so that it only allows (i.e. exposes an API), for example, creating new files in the retricted location, thus preventing historical output from being deleted/overwritten and removing the need to give standard users anything other than read access to the restricted location.

Another approach, that would be broadly similar but would avoid needint to write a windows service, would be to create a scheduled task that is configured to run under the "elevated user" that performs the actions in steps 1 through 5, but then configure it to allow it to be executed on demand (rather than on a schedule) by the application (I *think* this is possible but am not 100% sure).